# Is there a way to get a local timestamp in my IPython prompt?

Tags: windows-vista, prompt, ipython

Is there a way to get a local timestamp in my IPython prompt? I'm using IPython 0.10 and Python 2.6 on 64-bit Windows Vista.

My current default prompt is

```
[C:Python26/Scripts]
|9>
```

---

OK, I tried to follow your directions exactly. However, my experience has been that all config editing is best kept to my `ipy_user_conf.py`. To quote from it:

```
User configuration file for IPython (ipy_user_conf.py)

This is a more flexible and safe way to configure ipython than *rc files
(ipythonrc, ipythonrc-pysh etc.)

This file is always imported on ipython startup. You can import the
ipython extensions you need here (see IPython/Extensions directory).

Feel free to edit this file to customize your ipython experience.

Note that as such this file does nothing, for backwards compatibility.
Consult e.g. file 'ipy_profile_sh.py' for an example of the things 
you can do here.

See http://ipython.scipy.org/moin/IpythonExtensionApi for detailed
description on what you could do here.
```

So I now have these lines in main():

```
# -- prompt
# A different, more compact set of prompts from the default ones, that
# always show your current location in the filesystem:

o.prompt_in1 = r'\C_LightBlue[\C_LightCyan\Y2\C_LightBlue]\C_Normal\n\C_Green|\#>'
o.prompt_in2 = r'.\D: '
o.prompt_out = r'[\#] '
```

And I get this, for an example:

```
16:49:50 In[9]:1/7
1           [9] 0.14285714285714285

16:50:09 In[10]:
```

Questions:

1. What is that `1`?
2. How can I keep the current directory in the prompt? Before, I had

   ```
   [C:Python26/Scripts]
   |8>
   ```

---

Once more with feeling.
I'm so sorry for the mess I've made. I need to report the lines I either added or modified actually are:

```
import_all("os sys random datetime")
o.prompt_in1 = r'\C_LightBlue[\C_LightCyan\Y2\C_LightBlue]\C_Normal\n\C_Green|\#>'
o.prompt_in1 = r'${datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")}[\#]:'
o.prompt_out = r'[\#] '
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to edit your `ipythonrc` (in your home\_ipython directory), and add these lines:

```
import_mod datetime
prompt_in1 '${datetime.datetime.now()} In [\#]: '
# or
prompt_in1 '${datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")} In [\#]: '
```

Alternatively, you can also just add the `import_mod datetime` to the rc file, and add this to the main() function of `ipy_user_conf.py` (in the same directory):

```
o = ip.options
o.prompt_in1 = r'${datetime.datetime.now()} In [\#]: '
# or
o.prompt_in1 = r'${datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")} In [\#]: '
```

Comment: import_all("os sys random datetime")
    #execf('~/_ipython/ns.py')


    # -- prompt
    # A different, more compact set of prompts from the default ones, that
    # always show your current location in the filesystem:

    o.prompt_in1 = r'\C_LightBlue[\C_LightCyan\Y2\C_LightBlue]\C_Normal\n\C_Green|\#>'
    o.prompt_in2 = r'.\D: '
    o.prompt_out = r'[\#] '
    o.prompt_in1 = r'${datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")} In[\#]:'