# Python Spyder IDE Time stamp in IPython console

Tags: python, timestamp, anaconda, spyder

I am using Python2.7 Anaconda Spyder IDE. How can i add time stamp for commands in IPython console prompt. It will help track duration of the script. Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3879752/is-there-a-way-to-get-a-local-timestamp-in-my-ipython-prompt

Comment: no, this is outdated from 2011

Comment: Check out the magics: https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/interactive/magics.html, there is an example for how to add `timeit` very easily to a given command.